# Why is this interpreted as absolute url?

Tags: html, url

I want to *hide* my gitweb instance behind a reverse proxy. So I set my base url to `/gitweb` but some URLs are still broken.

As I debugged the problem I found that the following stylesheet is loaded from `/gitweb.css` instead of `/gitweb/gitweb.css`.

```
<base href="/gitweb" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gitweb.css"/>
```

I've found [a fix](https://technpol.wordpress.com/2013/08/12/proxying-rails-mediawiki-and-gitweb-with-apache2-mod_proxy-and-mod_proxy_html/) for this problem which says these links are interpreted as absolute urls. Unfortunately I'm not using Apache - which was used in the fix.

Anyway. I'm just wondering why `href="gitweb.css"` is not using the `base href`

Comment: Try adding a slash to the end of the path - `<base href="/gitweb/" />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He does, but the missing slash makes that the browser thinks "gitweb" is a page and only use the "/". Which is the same as base.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1889957/4516689

Or the example in the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata#the-base-element

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>This is an example for the &lt;base&gt; element</title>
        <base href="http://www.example.com/news/index.html">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Visit the <a href="archives.html">archives</a>.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

> The link in the above example would be a link to
>   "http://www.example.com/news/archives.html".

Comment: Makese sense and works. Seems like a bug in `gitweb.cgi` then.